# Event listners in AngularJs are not working on page reload

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a peculiar issue, when I reload the page before 'Logout' and then re-login, the page contents are not getting loaded.

Here is my code

```
    #login.js.coffee
    app.controller "LoginController", ["$scope", "$rootScope",
    ($scope, $rootScope) ->
        ......
        loginSuccess = (user) ->
          $rootScope.$broadcast 'event:user-authenticated'

         $scope.on "event:user-authenticated", ->
           console.log "Event received in login.js.coffee"
     --------------------------------------------------------------
    #contnet.js.coffee
    app.controller "ContentController", ["$scope",  "$rootScope",($scope, $rootScope) ->

        $scope.$on "event:user-authenticated", ->
           console.log "Event received in content.js.coffee"
    ]
```

Issue observed when I Reload the page -> Logout user -> Re-login

Only event listners in the same controller are working though I am sending the broadcast via'$rootScope'.

Only "Event received in login.js.coffee" log is printed in the console, the other message is not logged.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Can you make a plunker/fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller "LoginController", ["$scope", "$rootScope",
($scope, $rootScope) ->
    ......
    loginSuccess = (user) ->
      $rootScope.$broadcast 'event:user-authenticated'

     $rootScope.on "event:user-authenticated", ->
       console.log "Event received in login.js.coffee"
 --------------------------------------------------------------
#contnet.js.coffee
app.controller "ContentController", ["$scope",  "$rootScope",($scope, $rootScope) ->

    $rootScope.$on "event:user-authenticated", ->
       console.log "Event received in content.js.coffee"
]
```

Use `$rootScope.$on` instead of `$scope.$on` to catch `$rootScope.broadcast`